# Badge notifications is not appearing on icon

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Badge notifications is not appearing on icon
I am using this piece of code to show badge count in my uwp app (Windows specification version - 1903)

```
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument badgeXml = BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeGlyph);
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement badgeElement = badgeXml.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement;
badgeElement.SetAttribute("value", ObjFactory.Instance.CreateRuntimeData().BadgeMessageCount.ToString());
BadgeNotification badge = new BadgeNotification(badgeXml);
BadgeUpdater badgeUpdater = BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication();
badgeUpdater.Update(badge);
```

This code initially shows badge count properly but sometime it disappear suddenly most of the time after exiting the application.

So is there anything changed in code because code runs properly but doesn't show badge count or is there any issue at the system level?

Comment: During the testing,the badge will not disappear suddenly after exiting the application until call `BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Clear();` manually. please check if you have call clear method after existing app.

Comment: And if you just show the number badge, please set `BadgeTemplateType` as BadgeNumber.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I kind of solved the issue after your suggestion but again some of the users are facing it. So I want to know if there is any system-specific setting or any other reason?